# Understanding the relative ideal of thick curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be a smooth projective variety and $C\subset Y$ a smooth irreducible curve.
Let $C_i$ be $C$ with some $i$-fold structure (no need to specify which). Suppose we are in the situation: $$C_{i-1}\subset C_i\subset Y.$$ This just means that $Y$ contains an $i$-fold $C$, containing in turn an $(i-1)$-fold $C$. There is, then, an exact sequence of ideals $$0\to \mathscr I_{i}\to\mathscr I_{i-1}\to\mathscr I_{i-1}/\mathscr I_{i}\to 0,$$ where $\mathscr I_{i}\subset\mathscr O_Y$ is the ideal sheaf of $C_i$.

> **Question**. What does the quotient $\mathscr I_{i-1}/\mathscr I_{i}$
>   look like (as a sheaf on $Y$)?

I have the feeling it should equal $\mathscr O_C$, but I cannot prove it.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

No,  $\mathscr I_{i-1}/\mathscr I_{i}$ need  not be isomorphic to $\mathcal O_C$ .
For $i=2$ we may choose  $\mathscr I_1=\mathscr I_C$ and $\mathscr I_2=\mathscr I^2_C$, so that $\mathscr I_1/\mathscr I_2=\mathscr I_C/\mathscr I_C^2$    which is the conormal bundle $N^*_{C/Y}$  to $C$ in $Y$.
This bundle is not in general the trivial bundle $\mathcal O_C$: for example if $C$ is a line in $\mathbb P^2$ its  conormal bundle  is $\mathcal O_C(-1)$, which  has no non-zero section and is thus non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks Georges! I was wondering: $\mathscr I_C^2$ is not the ideal of a double $C$ in general, right? (for instance, $(y,z)^2=(y^2,yz,z^2)\subset k[x,y,z]$ is the *triple* $x$-axis) Is your answer still valid for $\dim Y\geq 3$ (i.e. $C$ not a divisor)?

Comment: Dear Brenin, yes the quotient sheaf $\mathscr I_C/\mathscr I_C^2$ is the conormal bundle of $C$ in $Y$ in any codimension, for any smooth subvariety of any smooth variety.

Comment: Sure! but my point was that if the codimension is higher than $1$, $\mathscr I_C^2$ may not be the ideal of a double $C$ anymore. So I was asking: is it still true that $\mathscr I_{i-1}/\mathscr I_i\neq\mathscr O_C$ (for other reasons)?

Comment: Dear Brenin,  by linearly embedding the  $\mathbb P^2$ of my example into $\mathbb P^3$ I think (but did not check) that you could adapt my counterexample to a counterexample in codimension $2$.

Comment: Dear Georges, I am sorry to still bother you, but I do not think that works. If I do that affine locally, say $I_C=(y)\subset k[x,y]$, then $I_C^2=(y^2)$ defines a double line in the plane, but $(y^2,z)\subset k[x,y,z]$ (the preimage of $I_C^2$ under $k[x,y,z]\to k[x,y]$) is not even a double line in $\mathbb A^3$: it is the $x$-axis with an embedded point.